# Output script to audio in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, media-player

I am playing around with algorithmic and generative music (at this point it's all generative noise).

I have a simple Python script which outputs numbers (ala "bytebeats"). I want to listen to the numbers as sound.

How can I play the output directly through my speakers in Ubuntu 13.04? I haven't been very successful searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

pyao (package name: `python-pyao`) will allow you to use libao under Python in order to output audio.

Comment: So, I have to rely on third party libraries for this utility? I was hoping there was some kind of native command line tool in linux.

Thanks, I will look into pyao.

Comment: Well, you could dump raw data into `paplay` or `aplay`, but since you're already using an actual language you should consider using something with proper bindings to that language.